# Spark. Keep partitioner after modifying key

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

first of all, sorry if this is a dump question, I'm kinda new with Spark.

I am trying to do some group operations in Spark and I'm trying to avoid extra shuffle when modifying the key of my RDD.

Original RDDs are json Strings

Simplifying the logic my code looks like this:

```
case class Key1 (a: String, b: String)

val grouped1: RDD[(Key1, String)] = rdd1.keyBy(generateKey1(_))
val grouped2: RDD[(Key1, String)] = rdd2.keyBy(generateKey2(_))

val joined: RDD[(Key1, (String, String)) = groped1.join(grouped2)
```

Now I want to include a new field in the key and do some reduce operations. So I have something like:

```
case class key2 (a: String, b: String, c: String)

val withNewKey: RDD[Key2, (String, String)] = joined.map{ case (key, (val1, val2)) => {
   val newKey = Key2(key.a, key.b, extractWhatever(val2))
   (newKey, (val1, val2))
}}

withNewKey.reduceByKey.....
```

If I'm not wrong, as the Key has changed the partition is lost, so the reduce operation will probably shuffle the data, but it doesn't make sense, as the key was extended and no shuffle would be needed.

Am I missing something? How can I avoid that shuffle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapPartitions` with `preservesPartitioning` set to `true`:

```
joined.mapPartitions(
  _.map{ case (key, (val1, val2)) => ... },
  true
)
```